# Hide rectangle if subreport is hidden

Tags: reporting-services, expression, subreport, ssrs-2012

I have a main report with a Tablix and in it there are two rows. In first row a sub report is displayed while in second row a rectangle is displayed. The rectangle is being used to give page breaks because page breaks inside sub report doesn't work.

I want to hide rectangle if sub report is also hidden. To hide sub report I am using following expression.

```
IIf(RowNumber(Nothing), True, False)
```

It works fine. But how can I also hide the rectangle below? Is there a way I can declare variable in expression and then use it in rectangle expression. For e.g. something like

```
IIf(RowNumber(Nothing), True, False)

If(RowNumber(Nothing))
      hideRectangle = True;
Else
      hideRectangle = True;

End If
```

And then using the variable hideRectangle in expression of rectangle like below?

```
IIf(hideRectangle = True, True, False)
```

Comment: Can you explain why you use `RowNumber(Nothing)` for hiding the sub report? Doesn't that same expression work for hiding the other row too? [The docs suggest](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms159225(v=sql.100).aspx) it just gets a row count for the dataset, which should be the same regardless of which row you're at.

Comment: Basically the main report inside which sub reports are running is using different data set than sub reports. Otherwise I would have used the same Exp on Subreport and Rectangle which are on Main Report.

Comment: I'm confused. Your main report has (1) a subreport and (2) a rectangle, yeah? Can't you use the visibility expression for (1) on (2) as well?

Comment: No both are using different data sets. One of the data available to sub report is not available in main report.